# Button inside of div has extra space on the left beyond padding

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to have a blue button, a divider, and another button.

The divider should be 30px away from the blue button and 30px away from the little arrow button. I have used padding for this purpose.

However the little arrow button is retaining some big white space on the left and I am not sure why.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a rule applied to padding for all divs in your code?

Comment: I think is has something to do with the text align. I have text align right applied to all elements shown here because I want them to be on the right hand side within the column

Comment: we need some code

Answer (score 0):

If a blue button is an image, then get sure that it has no extra space in image. Open button image in photoshop and trim extra space

Comment: No extra spacing on it